# Populating <select> with mysql data dynamically using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, templates

I'm stacked on this matter. I have a model that retrieves data from a mysql database

```
class load_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
}
Function loadsuppliers()
{       
    $this->db->select('SupplierID, Name');
    $records=$this->db->get('supplier');
    $data=array();

    foreach ($records->result() as $row)
    {
        $data[$row->SupplierID] = $row->Name;
    }
    return ($data);
}
```

}
?>

This model submits value to a function in my controller

```
public function getSupplier()
{
    $this->load->model('load_model');
    $data['unit'] = $this->load_model->loadsuppliers();
    $this->load->view('SupplierMGT', $data);

}
```

and I want to display the retrieved data to my view as a combo box. I tried to  check if I am able to retrieve database values using `echo json_encode($data)` and it returns `{"unit":{"2":"test","3":"Delta"}}` ,

Could you help me with this? I tried using

```
<?php foreach($unit as $result):
print_r($result); 
endforeach;?>
```

to check if i am able to pass the value but i failed.

Comment: what are you getting in $data['unit'] in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small changes in the model:

```
function loadsuppliers()
{       
    $this->db->select('SupplierID, Name');
    $records=$this->db->get('supplier');
    $data=array();
    if($records->num_rows() > 0){
        $data   = $records->result_array();
    }
    return ($data);
}
```

In your view `SupplierMGT.php` write this:

```
<select name="" id="" multiple="">
    <?php
        if(isset($unit) && is_array($unit) && count($unit) > 0){
            foreach($unit as $key=>$each){

    ?>
    <option value="<?=$each['SupplierID']?>"><?=$each['Name']?></option>
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh Thanks for that, i did not notice that my code is somehow working.... This idea is really helpful @Niloy Saha

Comment: Happie to help. Accept the answer if it helped you.